# How can I make my code write a python triangle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have been trying to make a triangle and use Turtle to draw it out. I want people to be able to import the values and my program will say if it is a triangle or not. If it it a triangle, then my program will write it out. If not, it will give errors. When I test my code, it says angle1 not defined. In line 56, I tried changing angle 1 and all the other parameters to numbers and it worked, but I want the user to enter numbers, not type them into the program. Don't worry about the math. I have all that code that I will add in. I just need help getting line 56 to work.

```
from turtle import *
canvas = Screen()
canvas.setup(400,200)

class Triangle(object):
    """Triangle"""
    sides = 3
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3, length1, length2, length3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3
        self.length1 = length1
        self.length2 = length2
        self.length3 = length3

    print "Enter the following inputs"
    angle1 = raw_input("Please enter Angle 1: ")
    print angle1
    angle2 = raw_input("Please enter Angle 2: ")
    print angle2
    angle3 = raw_input("Please enter Angle 3: ")
    print angle3
    length1 = raw_input("Please enter Length 1: ")
    print length1
    length2 = raw_input("Please enter Length 2: ")
    print length2
    length3 = raw_input("Please enter Length 3: ")
    print length3

    def description(self):
        print angle1
        print angle2
        print angle3
        print length1
        print length2
        print length3
        self.degrees()

    def check_Angles(self):
        "Lets Make sure the angles add up to 180"
        if self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180:
            print "That is a good Triangle"
            return True 
        else:
            print "That is not a good Triangle"
            return False

    def draw(self):
        if self.check_Angles():
            pen = Turtle()
            pen.forward(self.length1)
            pen.left(self.angle1)
            pen.forward(self.length2)
            pen.left(self.angle2)
            pen.forward(self.length3)

triangle2 = Triangle(angle1, angle2, angle3, length1, length2, length3)

triangle2.draw() 

canvas.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following rearrangement of your code will get it to run, but not necessarily to work.  I.e. it doesn't draw proper triangles -- but that's something you can teak in the now running code:

```
from turtle import *

canvas = Screen()
canvas.setup(400, 200)

class Triangle(object):
    """Triangle Class"""

    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3, length1, length2, length3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3
        self.length1 = length1
        self.length2 = length2
        self.length3 = length3

    def description(self):
        print angle1
        print angle2
        print angle3
        print length1
        print length2
        print length3

    def check_Angles(self):
        """Lets Make sure the angles add up to 180"""

        if self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180:
            print "That is a good Triangle"
            return True 
        else:
            print "That is not a good Triangle"
            return False

    def draw(self):
        if self.check_Angles():
            pen = Turtle()
            pen.forward(self.length1)
            pen.left(self.angle1)
            pen.forward(self.length2)
            pen.left(self.angle2)
            pen.forward(self.length3)

print "Enter the following values:"

angle1 = int(raw_input("Please enter Angle 1: "))
angle2 = int(raw_input("Please enter Angle 2: "))
angle3 = int(raw_input("Please enter Angle 3: "))

length1 = int(raw_input("Please enter Length 1: "))
length2 = int(raw_input("Please enter Length 2: "))
length3 = int(raw_input("Please enter Length 3: "))

triangle = Triangle(angle1, angle2, angle3, length1, length2, length3)

triangle.draw() 

canvas.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Ahh. Thank you soooo much. All I needed was the input. Now I can put the math calculations in and have it make a triangle. Thanks.